# Modify default customErrors message in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on an API project using .NET Framework 4.6.2 and have been looking for a simple way to suppress detailed error messages after an unhandled exception. The most straightforward option seems to be setting the customErrors mode to "On" in my web.config as follows:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

After this change, the following is returned when an unhandled exception occurs:

```
{
  "error": {
      "code": "",
      "message": "An error has occurred."
  }
}
```

This achieves the desired behavior because the exception stack trace is not surfaced, but is there a way to customize the message returned?

Comment: Wrap your code within a 
`try{
//... your code here
} 
catch (Exception ex){
    string errMessage = ex.Message;
//    ... Customize the message here
    throw new Exception(errMessage);
}`

But what kind of customizations are you aiming for in particular?

Comment: I was specifically trying to modify the generic message that .NET WebAPI inserts in the event of an unhandled exception while the customErrors mode is 'On'.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're aiming to customize the messages globally for your WebAPI, check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling

Comment: I think this is the right approach, thanks!